# Convert a rectangular grid of points into a hexagonal grid

Tags: c++, math, geometry

I have a rectangular grid of points like this[image] and I want to get indices of these points which forms a hexagonal grid like this [image].

How can I "Hexagonalize" the rectangular grid given that I want to draw only complete hexagons?

EDIT:

I added another picture showing what I want to achieve [image]

Comment: Are you trying to draw hexagons? Or are you trying to represent your hexagonal grid with a rectangular such that you are able to determine adjacency?

Comment: Amit's had [some great info on hex grids](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#coordinates) for ***years***.

Comment: @AdamBurry I'm trying to draw hexagons.  Right now I have a rectangular grid of points of size nxn.  I want to get the array indices from this rectangular grid which forms a hexagonal grid in the end.

Comment: @genpfault Thanks for the link! I did check, but I don't want to generate co-ordinates or anything.  All I need to do draw an hexagonal grid using a 2-D rectangular grid/array of points.

Comment: Also, I can't offset the co-ordinates, I generate these co-ordinates in a procedural way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two grids, one with dimensions N/2xN/2 where N=20, and the other is (N-1)/2+1x(N-1)/2+1. If the index called is odd, you go to the inner cells in your drawing with length N-1, otherwise the outer ones with length N.

I guess this would be the most economical/optimized way to go.

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't quite get you :(.  All I need to know is which co-ordinates in the rectangular grid makes into the hexagonal grid.  In the last figure, the co-ordinates:(0,1)(1,2)(2,2)(3,1)(2,0)(1,0) make up the first hexagon, how should I generalize this and get array indices for the entire hexagonal grid?

Comment: You can decompose your hexagonal grid into two, two-dimensional semi-rectangular grid. So, in your hexagonal grid picture, all the rows that have 16 elements can be taken into one rectangular array of size 16x16 (those are the rows that have even indices), and all the other rows that have 15 elements can be taken as another grid with size 15x15. Do you get the picture?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you want to do. If what you want to do is a hexagonal array that you can store data in it, then my way is the way to go. If you're talking about Geometry (which I find from your last edit), then maybe you just have to ignore my answer.

Comment: Precisely, all I need is the indices for the hexagonal-grid in the array, I have (x,y,z) cooridnates for each of these indices which I will use later.  But I still didn't quite get it, will think a bit more and update you.

Answer (score 0):

Your picture repeats every 2 units horizontally and every 4 vertically.  So you need to look at x mod 2 and y mod 4, and determine the lines based off of that.

---

To make that explicit:

```
(x mod 2,y mod 4) connections
(0,0)             top left to bottom right
(1,0)             bottom left to top right
(0,1)             bottom left to top left
(1,1)             bottom right to top right
(0,2)             bottom left to top right
(1,2)             top left to bottom right
(0,3)             bottom right to top right
(1,3)             bottom left to top left
```

---

From your comment, it appears that the numbers aren't assigned to the squares, they're assigned to the line immediately below or to their left (and that you listed the y-coordinate first).

Listing x first, the following sites are in the first hexagon, but not the second:
(1,0),(1,3),(0,2),(0,1)
the following sites are in no hexagon:
(0,0),(1,1),(1,2),(0,3)

If you look at (x mod 2,y mod 4), that splits your sites into the two lists that you need.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply! But, I don't need the connections, all I need to know is which indices of the rectangular grid make it into the hexagonal grid.  For example, (0,1)(1,2)(2,2)(3,1)(2,0)(1,0) make up the first grid, and I want ignore the points which don't make into the final hexagonal grid

Comment: So you are basically asking me to do this: `for(x= 0 to n){ for(y=0 to n){ new[x,y] = old[xmod2, ymod4]}}` ?

Comment: It depends on your implementation (and C++, whereas Java is the closest I come).  But yes.